# Integrability of $|x|^a \cdot |\log |x|\,|^b$ close to/away from the origin

Tags: real-analysis, integration

That's maybe a stupid question, but I got stuck with exercise 64 page 80 of Folland's "Real Analysis" (and I can't find a solution online). I hope you can suggest something.

Here's the exercise: 
For which $a$, $b$ real numbers is $|x|^a|\log |x||^b$ integrable over $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| < 1/2 \}$? And over $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| > 2 \}$?

Comment: Have you tried generalized spherical coordinates? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: Use Polar coordinates to reduce everything to the one-dimensional setting. You could also try $\int f \, d\mu= \int_0^\infty \mu(\{f >\lamda\}\,d\lambda$.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I got stuck with the integral in $\mathbb{R}$.